# how do i publish my flutter app on google play

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deployment, google-play

I'm trying to publish my Flutter app on the google play store, but it's not supported, as the application is being rejected due to the Permission "request installation packages": The use of permission is not directly related to the main purpose of the app, I've already checked the manifests and nowhere did I find this permission, does anyone know what that would be.

I've tried several ways, can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android. here you will get all the information regarding uploading to the play store and give you step-by-step guidance.